# parse string with regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have these fields.

```
$first_name = "first_name_5965_1_5969";

$email = "email_596231_1_596222";
```

How can I do some regex or only get the "0000_0_0000" part in php? Note that the numbers are always different but the format is the same.

Comment: You don't even need regex for this if the numbers are of fixed length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the regex for the same.

```
$email = "email_596231_1_596222";
preg_match('/\d*_\d_\d*$/', $email, $matches);
echo $matches[0];

Output:
596231_1_596222
```

If you want `0000_0_0000` format i.e. 4 digit in start and 4 digits at end then

```
preg_match('/\d{4}_\d_\d{4}/', $email, $matches);
echo $matches[0];

Output:
6231_1_5962
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
\d{4}_\d_\d{4}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/u5U5G6/1). That is four digits, a `_`, another digit, a `_`, another four digits and the end of the line/string.